# How can I set while repeat count per second?

Tags: java, loops

I use a while loop to repeat my codes in my program. I want to repeat a code 1000 times per second. How can I do this?

Comment: There is no direct method to guarantee that your loop will be executed exactly 1000x per second. You can, however, call [`Thread.sleep(long millis)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) to sleep for a fix amount of time in each iteration. Why must your loop execute exactly 1000 times per second? This seems like a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Does your code take less than 1ms to execute and do you care if the code is *not* executed evenly during 1 second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the *fixed-delay execution* of some code, it might be a better approach to use a **timer object**, such as [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), or even [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html), depending on what you're trying to accomplish. This being said, it's not possible to guarantee a frequency and a frequency of 1000/s (or period of 1ms) is quite fast, and `java.util.Timer` and `javax.swing.Timer` won't be able to keep up.

See also:

- [How to use swing timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [How to use Java.Util.Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095690/how-to-use-java-util-timer)
- [High Resolution Timer in Java 5](https://www.sagui.org/~gustavo/blog/code)

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a reasonably correct approach.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that it will execute it exactly 1000 times per second?

Comment: Your approach does not use a loop. I highly suspect that this is sufficient for OP, but it would be better to ask for clarification in the comments before posting a speculative answer.

Comment: @Blobonat you can never guarantee that something will be called `n` times per second (or any other unit). However, using a standard Timer will give you the best chance of getting the closest to that goal.

Comment: @Fureeish Thats why I downvoted the answer, because it does not mention it.

Comment: @Blobonat but it provides the optimal solution to the problem. While the addition of it being never guaranteed, I believe this is the answer.

Comment: I guess the best solution is this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I will show you an example of this using `System.nanoTime()` to determine how much time has passed, and will explain why your premise typically does not make much sense and you probably should not do this.

First off here is code that will execute a block of code 1000 times and will take 1 second to finish every time, as long as that code *can* be executed that quickly.

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
long currentTime = startTime;
int counter = 0;
while (((currentTime - startTime) < 1_000_000_000) || counter < 1000) { //Executes until 1 second has passed AND it has iterated 1000 times
    counter++;
    currentTime = System.nanoTime();
    if (counter < 1000) {
        //The code you want to execute 1000 times
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
System.out.println((currentTime - startTime)/1_000_000 + " milliseconds have passed.");
```

Now the problem with this code is you will obviously hit the `1000` executions *before* you hit 1 second, so it will sit in the loop doing nothing after the `1000` executions are completed to ensure the total time of the loop takes 1 second.

However what happens if that block of code takes so long that you *cannot* complete that code 1000 times within a second?  It  is impossible to go the other direction and add *extra* time to complete the 1000 executions, the 1000 executions will no longer take 1 second and it is impossible to fix this.  The *only* way this can be done, is if you know that 1000 executions will be completed *under* 1 second and wait for the remaining time.

However, this does not seem like a good way to do things in general and you should not program in a way that depends on time AND loop iteration count, it just does not really make sense and there are likely better ways to do what your actual goal is.

**Note:**  This code will only execute the block of code 1000 times, a single time.  Surround all of this code by another loop if you want to do this multiple times.

**EDIT:**

Just to make it more clear I made an example that will take *longer* to execute than 1 second.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    long currentTime = startTime;
    int counter = 0;
    while (((currentTime - startTime) < 1_000_000_000) || counter < 1000) {
        counter++;
        currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        if (counter < 1000) { 
            //The code you want to execute 1000 times
            int count2 = 0;
            while (count2 < 1000) { //1000 blank lines per loop to take a long time
                count2++;
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
    System.out.println((currentTime - startTime)/1_000_000 + " milliseconds have passed.");
}
```

This will print blank lines just to ensure it takes a long time.  For my system this outputted:

```
2831 milliseconds have passed.
```

The code took 2.8 seconds because time was no longer the restrictive condition, but 1000 iterations was, and there is no way to make this exact code run 1000 times per second, it is impossible.

**TLDR:**  You can force something to take a *minimum* amount of a time, but you cannot force it to take a *maximum* amount of time.

Comment: _if you know that 1000 executions will be completed under 1 second and wait for the remaining time._ I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a thread and use Thread.sleep() or System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000, this will give you the time in seconds.